# IE 7/8 rendering issue?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, haml

Within ie8, the document is rendered as intended.
[image: ie8 screenshot]

Within ie7, the document is not
[image: ie7 screenshot]

(built on top of bootstrap with additional css)

markup:

```
.modal.fade.in#unsupported-browser-modal
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-text
        .modal-header
          %h3.modal-title YOUR BROWSER IS OUT OF DATE
        .modal-body
          This website requires a minimum of Internet Explorer version 9 or the latest version of other popular web browsers.
```

additional css:

```
#unsupported-browser-modal {

  .modal-dialog, .modal-content {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none;
    min-width: none;
  }

  .modal-content {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }

  .modal-header {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    min-height: 16.42857143px;
  }

  .modal-title {
      font-family : $var;
      text-align     : center;
      font-weight    : bold;
      letter-spacing : 2px;
      margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .modal-body {
    font-family: $var1;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 35px 80px;
    color: #646464;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}

#unsupported-browser-modal.modal {
  display: block;
}

.modal-text {
  top: 37%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Also, document.compatMode seems to be set to the same value in both ie7 as well as i8, in case that may be of interest.

Thoughts as to what I may not be accounting for?

Comment: Throw markup / css in a JSFiddle or something.

Comment: http://codepen.io/ahcarpenter/pen/oXgQdP @MathiasaurusRex also, thanks a ton for having a look!

Comment: Try adding `html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNmQbG

Comment: The  irony is that codepen doesn't work in IE7

Comment: @HiddenHobbes no avail, but I most certainly appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: @Drew Is there anything in particular that isn't working with my suggestion? I gave it a go and it seemed to work in IE7 (well IE11 emulating IE7).

Comment: @HiddenHobbes, had added the additional rules, and tested in ie7 (vm), but very well may have done something wrong?

Also, had wound up adding '#height: 100%' to the '#unsupported-browser-modal.modal' selector, in case that may be of interest!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what your looking for. It's also, a bit of an hack so I wouldn't suggest it unless no one suggests a solution/you don't find one. But try:

```
_margin-top: 100px; /* ie7 only */
```

Can read more about safe CSS hacks if your interested here:https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks#css-hacks

Comment: would like to ensure that the the text is centered vertically as well as horizontally within a responsive layout